# Round dead patches in lawn - Suggestions for cause (and remedy), please?

Tags: lawn, lawn-repair

Location: Australia, Albury/Wodonga area (far north Victoria).

About two months ago I noticed some brown patches in the Kikuyu lawn, which quickly became mainly circular 15-25cm diameter before slowly growing randomly and joining other patches.

Was watering deeply once a week during Summer, up until the (Wet) autumn and winter started.
Grass was nicely green all over before, so no dry patches or subsurface rocks/roots suspected.

The two current photos show a closeup and overall view of the lawn. (I have greyed out an area of physical damage so as to not cause confusion.)

Suggestions for a cause, and any remedies for this, would be much appreciated!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you Rohit, (for the answer, and for the typo fix!) It's fairly obvious to me now that I've read your link about Brown Patch, that the trigger was watering for shorter periods _Three_ times in one night, once per week (as the soil is not porous, and too much runoff happens otherwise). Obviously the all night wetting created ideal conditions for fungus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks rather like your problem.  According to [Brown Patch](https://www.kiwicare.co.nz/problem/brown-patch/), it is a fungal disease.

> [image]
> Brown patch is a fungal disease affecting the roots of lawn grasses. Symptoms begin with small areas of discoloured grass and spread to brown off and kill areas up to 1 metre. Examination of grass roots will show roots turning black.

So look for appropriate fungicides, examples

- LawnPro Fungus Control
- Mancozeb Plus Garden Fungicide and Miticide